# How to pass console input to xargs

Tags: xargs

I am trying to pass a file name as an argument to `wc -l` through `xargs`. 
Below is the command I tried:

```
cat > xargs wc -l
```

I am getting below error

> ```
> cat: invalid option -- 'l'
> Try 'cat --help' for more information.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting `stdout` to `xargs`, use pipes:

```
cat | xargs wc -l
```